# Qt python How to know which signals QPushButton sends?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, signals

Can you please help me how to find a full list of signals which QWidget sends?

For example, `QPushButton` sends `"clicked()"` when it is clicked. I tried to find which signal button sends when key is pressed but I couldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just read the [`QPushButton`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html) documentation. Either it has a "Signals" section, which will list its own signals and a link to its ancestors signals, or it doesn't define signals of its own and you should look at the "Additional Inherited Members" section. (Same for all other Qt classes.)

For `QPushButton`, the only four widget signals (apart from those of `QWidget` and `QObject`) are the signals inherited from `QAbstractButton`:

- `clicked(bool checked=false)`
- `pressed()`
- `released()`
- `toggled(bool)`

Read the respective signal documentation for details. In other words, there are no specific slots for the action triggered on a button when you press a key. You'll need to implement key event handlers if you need specific behavior for that.

Comment: thanks. I thought that every control sends appropriate signal on every event

Comment: @Mat @ekhumoro so I should pass something like a tag to the function(slot) when I add that function to that button as a result of its signal? like `self.push_button.clicked.connect(self.update_plot(push_button))` ?

Comment: @Shahriar.M Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have a different problem. Very few people will look at these comments.